# apache2 server not working

Tags: 18.04, apache2

For some reason my apache2 has stopped working. I have tried uninstalling it, the problem still remains the same. Here's some commands and their results that I have tried which might help you:

`sudo systemctl status apache2`:

```
● apache2.service - The Apache HTTP Server
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/apache2.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Sun 2020-06-21 13:41:56 IST; 13min ago
     Docs: https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/
  Process: 19571 ExecStart=/usr/sbin/apachectl start (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)

Jun 21 13:41:56 kabir systemd[1]: apache2.service: Control process exited, code=exited status=1
Jun 21 13:41:56 kabir systemd[1]: apache2.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Jun 21 13:41:56 kabir systemd[1]: Failed to start The Apache HTTP Server.
Jun 21 13:41:56 kabir apachectl[19571]: AH00558: apache2: Could not reliably determine the server's fully qualified domain name, using 127.0.1
Jun 21 13:41:56 kabir apachectl[19571]: (98)Address already in use: AH00072: make_sock: could not bind to address [::]:80
Jun 21 13:41:56 kabir apachectl[19571]: (98)Address already in use: AH00072: make_sock: could not bind to address 0.0.0.0:80
Jun 21 13:41:56 kabir apachectl[19571]: no listening sockets available, shutting down
Jun 21 13:41:56 kabir apachectl[19571]: AH00015: Unable to open logs
Jun 21 13:41:56 kabir apachectl[19571]: Action 'start' failed.
Jun 21 13:41:56 kabir apachectl[19571]: The Apache error log may have more information.
```

`sudo systemctl restart apache2`:

```
Job for apache2.service failed because the control process exited with error code.
See "systemctl status apache2.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.
```

`netstat -an | grep ":80"`:

```
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:80              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN     
tcp        0      0 192.168.43.128:33944    117.18.237.29:80        TIME_WAIT  
tcp        0      0 192.168.43.128:33864    117.18.237.29:80        ESTABLISHED
tcp        0      0 192.168.43.128:34524    23.217.53.84:80         ESTABLISHED
tcp        0      0 192.168.43.128:54364    172.217.166.163:80      ESTABLISHED
tcp        0      0 192.168.43.128:54206    172.217.166.163:80      TIME_WAIT  
tcp        0      0 192.168.43.128:33946    117.18.237.29:80        ESTABLISHED
tcp        0      0 192.168.43.128:34522    23.217.53.84:80         ESTABLISHED
tcp6       0      0 :::80                   :::*                    LISTEN
```

`sudo apachectl start`:

```
Invoking 'systemctl start apache2'.
Use 'systemctl status apache2' for more info.
Job for apache2.service failed because the control process exited with error code.
See "systemctl status apache2.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.
Action 'start' failed.
The Apache error log may have more information.
```

`sudo netstat -lnap`:

```
Active Internet connections (servers and established)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State       PID/Program name    
 -                   
tcp6       0      0 :::80                   :::*                    LISTEN      1276/nginx: master
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:80              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1276/nginx: master
```

Comment: Seems you have another program that usurps the **port 80** (Address already in use).Despite of the fact that the Apache status is **failed** ,you have ```0.0.0.0:80``` in your **netstat** output.Have you another http server or some program that might be used as a http server ?

Comment: I don't know I tried to install kali tools and since then this is happening

Comment: OK.Run ```netstat -anp``` to see which program is occupying the port.

Comment: Its a huge list what am I looking for here?

Comment: Just look for 0.0.0.0:80.And find the PID and name of the program which occupies the port.

Comment: I have updated it in the question, I have also updated the apache command result

Comment: If possible , please run **netstat** with sudo.

Comment: I just ran ``sudo netstat`` but now I can't find ``0.0.0.0:80``

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/109639/discussion-between-parsa-mousavi-and-anonymous-chatbox).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot have two HTTP servers listening on the same port in the same machine(The exception is when you put them on different interfaces or when you use [Bridge Network Connections](https://wiki.debian.org/BridgeNetworkConnections)) .Looks the **nginx** server is running in your system , so if you want to use Apache2 instead , you can stop the **nginx** service :

```
sudo service nginx stop
```

and if you want to prevent **nginx** to start automatically at boot time (which might prevent apache2 to start or even vice versa) you can disable its service via **systemctl** :

```
sudo systemctl disable nginx
```